# Continuations using Async CTP

Tags: continuations, c#-5.0, async-ctp

Is it possible to use Async CTP to emulate continuations and tail recursion?

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
async Task Loop(int count)
{
    if (count == 0)
        retrun;

    await ClearCallStack();
    //is it possible to continue here with a clean call stack?
    Loop(count -1)
}
```

I guess one needs a custom scheduler and such, but would it be possible?
(that is, can it be used to recurse w/o blowing the call stack)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely possible.

In the newest Async CTP (Refresh for VS2010 SP1), there's a "GeneralThreadAffineContext" class in the Unit Testing sample (either in VB or C#). That provides the requisite helper code for just running an async method in a general purpose thread-affine manner.

By thread affinity, we mean that the async continuations get processed on the same context as the original thread, similarly to the behavior for WinForms/WPF, but without spinning up the real WPF or WinForms message loop.

`Task.Yield()`'s design is to defer the rest of the current method to the SynchronizationContext, so you don't even need to write your own `await ClearCallStack()`. Instead, your sample will boil down to:

```
async Task DoLoop(int count)
{
    // yield first if you want to ensure your entire body is in a continuation
    // Final method will be off of Task, but you need to use TaskEx for the CTP
    await TaskEx.Yield();

    if (count == 0)
        return;

    //is it possible to continue here with a clean call stack?
    DoLoop(count -1)
}

void Loop(int count)
{
    // This is a stub helper to make DoLoop appear synchronous. Even though
    // DoLoop is expressed recursively, no two frames of DoLoop will execute
    // their bodies simultaneously
    GeneralThreadAffineContext.Run(async () => { return DoLoop(count); });
}
```

Comment: Where are those extensions located? I've got the SP1 async refresh installed.. cant find yield nor generalthreadaffinecontext

Comment: GeneralThreadAffineContext isn't part of the official API - it's actually some helper code in the unit testing sample. Also, for the CTP purposes, Yield() is a method off of TaskEx because our goal was to have the CTP framework APIs to be deployable without having to patch the .NET framework.